# Duplicate seed entries with nested object models after save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Seeding function is creating duplicate entries within the traits array.

```js
var seedGenres = () => {
  seedData.genres.forEach((seed) => {
    Genre.create({
      name: seed.name
    }, (err, newGenre) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else{
        console.log("Genre Created")
        seed.traits.forEach((trait) => {
          Trait.create({
            name: trait.name,
            upvoteScore: 0,
            downvoteScore: 0,
            totalVotes: 0
          }, (err, newTrait) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err, newTrait)
            } else {
              newGenre.traits.push(newTrait)
              newGenre.save()
              console.log(newGenre.traits)
              console.log('Trait pushed succesffuly')
            }
          })
        })
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Genre.model.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var genreSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  traits: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Trait"
    }
  ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Genre", genreSchema)
```

Trait.model.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

var traitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  upvoteScore: Number,
  downvoteScore: Number,
  totalVotes: Number
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Trait", traitSchema)
```

Basically we want to seed some genres each with 3 traits, when console logging what it's doing, it seems to be correct. However, when viewing the collection after it's done running, there are 6 trait entries under each genre (double what we're expecting)

This is what we're expecting

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4971"),
    "name" : "RPG",
    "traits" : [
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4974"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4975"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4973")
    ],
    "__v" : 3
}

This is the output that we are currently getting.

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4971"),
    "name" : "RPG",
    "traits" : [
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4974"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4974"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4975"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4974"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4975"),
        ObjectId("59ad8a73fa7058a4dc9c4973")
    ],
    "__v" : 3
}

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be on you mixing synchronous `for` loops with asynchronous Mongoose operations.

My first suggestion would be to change `push` to [addToSet()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.addToSet).

My second suggestion would be to use [async.js](http://caolan.github.io/async/).

```
async.mapSeries(seedData.genres, (seed, cb1) => {
    Genre.create({ name: seed.name }, (err, newGenre) => {
        // stop mapSeries() if an error occurs
        if (err) return cb1(err);

        console.log("Genre Created")

        // create traits
        async.eachSeries(seed.traits, (trait, cb2) => {
            Trait.create({ name: trait.name, upvoteScore: 0, downvoteScore: 0, totalVotes: 0 }, (err, newTrait) => {
                // stop eachSeries() if an error occurs
                if (err) return cb2(err);

                console.log("Trait Created")

                // add trait to genre
                newGenre.traits.push(newTrait);
                // mark current async task as done
                cb2();
            });
        }, err => {
            // if an error occurred during eachSeries()
            if (err) return cb1(err);
            // otherwise, save the genre
            newGenre.save(cb1);
        });
    })
}, (err, genres) => {
    // if an error occurred during the operations, it will come here
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('DONE!', genres);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply - so I actually had changed `push` to using `addToSet` and that seemed to work for the dupes.  Now, when seeding everything (users, games, genres, traits) - one of the genres will only get 2 of the 3 traits... I'm going to dig into your suggestion about the sync vs. async looping - thank you!